# How do I set up Visual Studio 2019 on a local git repository which already exists?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

All the literature states that there should be no problem to set up multiple clients to the same local git repository. Indeed, I already have Visual Studio 2015 and SourceTree both set up on the same local repository with no problem. My question is specifically how to set up Visual Studio 2019 on a local git repository which is already populated. The Wizard which takes me through the process within the VS 2019 IDE balks when I select a local folder which is already populated.

[image]

So what is the process to connect VS 2019 to a repository which already exists, as opposed to creating a new repository?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I find that simply opening a solution file from within the local git repository automatically connects me to the server. I can view history, commit, sync, etc. It looks like I was looking for a process which is simply unnecessary. It looks like all the connection information is stored within the local git itself and Visual Studio 2019 automatically connects using this information.

It all just works seamlessly.